# Login problems connecting with SQL Server in nodejs

Tags: node.js, sql-server, azure-data-studio

I'm working in osx with SQL Server using a docker image to be able to use it, running:

```
docker run -d --name sqlserver -e 'ACCEPT_EULA=Y' -e 'SA_PASSWORD=myStrongPass' -e 'MSSQL_PID=Developer' -p 1433:1433 microsoft/mssql-server-linux:2017-latest
```

I can connect successfully in `Azure Data Studio GUI` with the following configuration

[image]

But the connection does not works in my `nodejs` code using `mssql` module.

```
const poolConnection = new sql.ConnectionPool({
  database: 'myDbTest',
  server: 'localhost',
  port: 1433,
  password: '*******',
  user: 'sa',
  connectionTimeout: 5000,
  options: {
    encrypt: false,
  },
});

const [error, connection] = await to(poolConnection.connect());
```

The error always is the same:

```
ConnectionError: Login failed for user 'sa'
```

Is my first time working with SQL Server and is confusing for me the fact that I can connect correctly in the Azure Studio GUI but I can't do it in code.

---

I'm trying create new login users with `CREATE LOGIN` and give them privileges based on other post here in stackoverflow but nothing seems to work.

---

**UPDATE:**

I realize that i can connect correctly if i put master in database key.

Example:

```
const poolConnection = new sql.ConnectionPool({
  database: 'master', <- Update here
  server: 'localhost',
  port: 1433,
  password: '*******',
  user: 'sa',
  connectionTimeout: 5000,
  options: {
    encrypt: false,
  },
});
```

[image]

1) Db that i can connect

2) Db that i want to connect but i can't.

Container error

```
2020-03-18 03:59:14.11 Logon       Login failed for user 'sa'. Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified database 'DoctorHoyCRM'. [CLIENT: 172.17.0.1]
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect a lot of people miss the sa password complexity requirement:

> The password should follow the SQL Server default password policy, otherwise the container can not setup SQL server and will stop working. By default, the password must be at least 8 characters long and contain characters from three of the following four sets: Uppercase letters, Lowercase letters, Base 10 digits, and Symbols. You can examine the error log by executing the docker logs command.

An example based on: [Quickstart: Run SQL Server container images with Docker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-docker?view=sql-server-linux-2017)

```sh
docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest
docker run -e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" -e "SA_PASSWORD=myStr0ngP4ssw0rd" -e "MSSQL_PID=Developer" -p 1433:1433 --name sqlserver -d mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest
docker start sqlserver
```

Checking that the docker image is running (it should not say "Exited" under STATUS)...

```sh
docker ps -a
# CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                                                      COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
# af9f01eacab2        mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest                                 "/opt/mssql/bin/nonr…"   45 seconds ago      Up 34 seconds       0.0.0.0:1433->1433/tcp   sqlserver
```

Testing from within the docker container that SQL Server is installed and running...

```sh
docker exec -it sqlserver /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd \
   -S localhost -U "sa" -P "myStr0ngP4ssw0rd" \
   -Q "select @@VERSION"

# --------------------------------------------------------------------
# Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-CU19) (KB4535007) - 14.0.3281.6 (X64) 
#   Jan 23 2020 21:00:04 
#   Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation
#   Developer Edition (64-bit) on Linux (Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS)
```

Finally, testing from NodeJS...

```js
const sql = require('mssql');

const config = {
    user: 'sa',
    password: 'myStr0ngP4ssw0rd',
    server: 'localhost',
    database: 'msdb',
};

sql.on('error', err => {
    console.error('err: ', err);
});

sql.connect(config).then(pool => {
    return pool.request()
        .query('select @@VERSION')
}).then(result => {
    console.dir(result)
}).catch(err => {
    console.error('err: ', err);
});
```

```js
$ node test.js
tedious deprecated The default value for `config.options.enableArithAbort` will change from `false` to `true` in the next major version of `tedious`. Set the value to `true` or `false` explicitly to silence this message. node_modules/mssql/lib/tedious/connection-pool.js:61:23
{
  recordsets: [ [ [Object] ] ],
  recordset: [
    {
      '': 'Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-CU19) (KB4535007) - 14.0.3281.6 (X64) \n' +
        '\tJan 23 2020 21:00:04 \n' +
        '\tCopyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation\n' +
        '\tDeveloper Edition (64-bit) on Linux (Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS)'
    }
  ],
  output: {},
  rowsAffected: [ 1 ]
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer, but my password is really strong. Even the `docker exec` command works for me. My problem still happening only in nodejs code. Your example doesn't work for me either.

Comment: I realize that i can connect correctly if i put `master` in `database` key